# Rails 3: How do I write forms that don't align exactly with the structure of the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example, if I have a simple model with a time attribute named `start_time`, then the straight-forward form code would be...

```
<%= form_for newObj do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_time %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :start_time %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But I would like to have two text fields, one for the date component of the `time` object and one for the time component of the `time` object.

1. How would I structure that form code?
2. In the controller, how do I want to organize the data being sent to the form? Do I want to separate the two components of the time object?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this probably isn't a direct answer to your question, but might provide a good starting point:

There is a Rails view helper `select_datetime` which generates drop-down menus for date and time entries (rather than a text field). See documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_datetime

Ryan Bates did a couple of related railscasts (links are to asciicasts, should contain a link to original video):

- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/32-time-in-text-field
  This deals with the above mentioned drop-downs being fiddly and goes through using a text-field instead. Code in here could help for doing two separate text-fields for date and time entry.
- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/213-calendars
  This talks about javascript calendar widgets.

Answer (score 1):

We can use virtual attribute here

```
class YourModel < AR::Base
  def start_time_ar=ar
    start_time = DateTime.parse(ar.join(" "))
  end
end
```

so in your view:

```
<%= form_for newObj do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Date" %>
    <%= text_field_tag "#{f.object_name}[start_time_ar][]" %><br />
    <%= f.label "Time" %>
    <%= text_field_tag "#{f.object_name}[start_time_ar][]" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a calendar or the `datetime_select`helper is a good way since it would remove some of the formatting problems you might have with inputs (dateformats are not standardized throughout the world, use of AM/PM or 24H etc.).

And, splitting it up would allow you to do make most of the work automatically.
Say for instance that you have your `:start_time` attribute, then you create a field for `start_time(1i)` for the year, `start_time(2i)` for the month, `start_time(3i)` for the day etc. and when passed to the model, ActiveRecord will put it automatically into a datetime.